# How execute a command on each Sequelize connection?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I need to set a Mysql session variable (`aurora_replica_read_consistency`) on each Sequelize connection for my nodejs application.

I can set this session variable with the below code, but I'm pretty sure this won't be set for all Sequelize connections, that I need a way of setting this each time a new DB connection is opened/added to the connection pool.

```
await sequelize.query("set aurora_replica_read_consistency = 'eventual'");
```

Is there a way to configure this session variable on my Sequeilize instance, or to extend/override Sequelize such that I can set this each time a new connection is created?

Answer (score 0):

Old questions, but if other come by you can use sequelize hooks to set a session variable on every connection:

```
sequelize.addHook('afterConnect', (connection) => {
  // This function will be called after each successful connection
  connection.query('SET aurora_replica_read_consistency = "eventual"', (err) => {
    if (err) {
      // Handle any errors that may occur during the query execution
      console.error('Failed to set session variable:', err);
    } else {
      console.log('Session variable set successfully for the new connection');
    }
  });
});
```